# Issue with Shareplum. Can't find "folder" attribute

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to download a text file from my sharepoint using the following code.

```
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365
from shareplum import folder

authcookie = Office365('https://my.sharepoint.com', username='username', password='password').GetCookies()
site = Site('https://my.sharepoint.com/', authcookie=authcookie)

folder_1 = site.folder('Shared Documents/This folder')
folder_1.download_file('test.txt')
```

I get the following error when I run the code:

```
AttributeError: '_Site2007' object has no attribute 'folder'
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5):

I am able to reproduce your issue. Please add following parameter in your code:

```
from shareplum.site import Version

site = Site('https://my.sharepoint.com',version=Version.v365, authcookie=authcookie)
```

After i specify the version, it works well!

Comment: This seems to work for some Office365 versions, too